# Different methods to find orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Say I have a set of vectors and I want to find a basis for the orthogonal complement. I know a way to do this is to just calculate the dot product of each given vector with a general vector. This way you get a system of linear equations and you solve it (this is just finding the nullspace of the matrix that represents the system).

But I came across another way of finding the complement. From what I understood, you can extend the given set to a basis for the entire space (e.g. extend a set of 3 vectors in R⁴ to a basis of R⁴) and then use the Gram-Schmidt process on this extended basis. Apparently you have to use the vector you added to extend the basis last (which I believe I understand why). In the case of R⁴, the last vector is a basis for the orthogonal complement.

The question is: is this method valid? I can see why this process would work, but I don't understand why you would use it.

Comment: “I can see why this process would work...” Doesn’t this answer your immediately preceding question?

Comment: I'm not very confident when I say that. I realize it's formulated weirdly. I just wanted confirmation that either method is correct.

Comment: Ah. Well, think about what happens at each iteration of G-S: you compute the orthogonal rejection of the next vector from the span of the ones that have already been processed.